# Java - find all combinations of three numbers in sorted array that have a sum smaller than a number

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

The title is a mouthful so I will explain further. This is a question out of a practice test for my introduction to computer science course. Most of the questions I was able to solve by myself or find a solution online, but not for this one.

You are given a sorted array (`int[] arr`) of unique integers (positive and negative). You must find how many triplets (combinations of three numbers in the array) have a sum that is less than a given number (`int num`).

The method signature is:
`public static int countTriplets (int [] arr, int num)`

The catch is that it must be done with the lowest possible time complexity. If I understand correctly, iterating over all the possible combinations with nested for loops would give me a time complexity of O(n^3). However, I can't think of any other solution.

I should also mention that the array should be used as an array, without using other Java classes like ArrayList.

Any help is appreciated. It doesn't have to be a complete solution in code, even just a general idea of how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two approaches for this **3-sum smaller** problem:
Since the array is already sorted, you can jump right in with either algorithm.

- Binary search approach O(n^2logn)
- Two pointer approach : O(n^2)

I would attempt the two-pointer approach. Take a look on Leetcode for 2-sum and 3-sum problem since this is a variation of it. Best of luck!

Comment: Knowing the name of the problem cetainly helps. I went with the two pointer approach. Do you know how I could revise such a question in the future to avoid getting downvoted? I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: I was honestly not bothered by the question and I enjoy Leetcode/coding problems, so I wanted to point you in the right direction. You provided enough details of your understanding of the brute force approach and asked for a general idea of how to optimize the time complexity which was a straight forward question. If you haven't read the how-to-ask questions, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Keep grinding my friend :)